# Is this a correct rel next/prev and canonical strategy for paginated listing URLs?

Tags: seo, url-parameters, pagination, rel-canonical

I have listing pages of this format:

```
www.example.com/xyz/abc/pageNo?x=X&y=Y
```

The URL parameters only are used for sorting purpose. "pageNo" is the page number.

Here the URL parameters are not mandatory. So, I also render results for:

```
www.example.com/xyz/abc/pageNo
```

Currently, the way I have the canonicals URLs is:

URL: `www.example.com/xyz/abc/1?x=X&y=Y`
Canonical: `www.example.com/xyz/abc/1`
Next: `www.example.com/xyz/abc/2`

URL: `www.example.com/xyz/abc/2?x=X&y=Y`
Canonical: `www.example.com/xyz/abc/2`
Prev: `www.example.com/xyz/abc/1`
Next: `www.example.com/xyz/abc/3`

URL: `www.example.com/xyz/abc/2`
Canonical: `www.example.com/xyz/abc/2`
Prev: `www.example.com/xyz/abc/1`
Next: `www.example.com/xyz/abc/3`

Is this implementation correct from the SEO standpoint?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what/how you sort.

#### `canonical`

If page `/xyz/abc/1` contains {"A", "B", "C"}, and if page `/xyz/abc/1?x=X` contains {"B", "C", "D"}, it would be **wrong** to say that `/xyz/abc/1?x=X` has the canonical URL `/xyz/abc/1`.

If page `/xyz/abc/1` contains {"A", "B", "C"}, and if page `/xyz/abc/1?x=X` contains {"C", "B", "A"}, it would be **correct** to say that `/xyz/abc/1?x=X` has the canonical URL `/xyz/abc/1`.

In other words: a canonical URL *must* contain the same content, and *may* contain additional content.

So if the sorting changes which items are on a specific page, don’t use `canonical` like that. If you still want to use `canonical`, either point to a page that contains all items, or use it to point to a canonical sorting of the parameters (so `?z=X&x=X` could have the canonical URL `?x=X&z=Z`).

#### `next` / `prev`

And no matter which case is yours, you probably want to keep the parameters for the `next`/`prev` URLs.

A visitor that has sorting `x=X` on page 2 will likely want to have the same sorting on page 3, and in case the visitor goes back to page 2, will likely want to see the same sorting as before.

So `/xyz/abc/2?x=X&y=Y` should have:

- Prev: `/xyz/abc/1?x=X&y=Y`
- Next: `/xyz/abc/3?x=X&y=Y`

Comment: Thanks @unor.That brought some clarity  
Would you recommend blocking parameterized URLs for SEO i.e. to prevent devaluing my listing page by having a lot of variants based on URL params?
Also, I was observing the canonicals on Amazon and saw that all the below mentioned links had the same canonical URL
https://goo.gl/1YSYvL

Newest Arrivals
https://goo.gl/BMqQ91

Low to high
https://goo.gl/Qo5zGB

New and Popular
https://goo.gl/1YSYvL

Neither their robots.txt blocks these pages nor are they marked as no-index.
Is this a wrong practice or am I missing something?

Comment: @HBalyan: I’d say Amazon’s `canonical` implementation is wrong (per [RFC 6596](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6596)) if these are really separate pages, and not just one page using a JavaScript pager (hiding/showing items on the same page). --- Regarding blocking: I think I would `noindex` the parameterized URLs if the sorting is just something like alphabetical/price/date etc., but I haven’t given it much thought.

Answer (score 0):

If `x` and `y` parameters doesn't change the page's content then it is the right way to do it.

Remember to also include only the `prev`/ `canonical` attribute in the final page.

Comment: Thanks @marcanuy.
I implemented in this manner cause I thought that variations using those params would not change the sorting order much.
But I figured that this implementation is actual wrong because in certain cases the sorting is quite different from that of the canonicals.
Also, I do not want to dilute the value of the page as URL parameters would actually lead to a lot of variations of the same product category listing and hamper the SEO.
An expert suggested that to block the parameterized versions to prevent dilution.
What is the best SEO way of handling paginated listings?

Comment: @HBalyan Categorize parameters with the URL Parameters tool https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/crawl-url-parameters